# Info Path - Check value inserted is not present in list

Tags: list, infopath

There is an external list in SP with Infopath form. I need to check if project number in Add New Item form already exists in list, it shows an error or pop up message to say it already exists in list. 
I am new to InfoPath so couldn't figure out this issue.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer work with Infopath, and I can't recall what everything is called precisely, but conceptually, you need to:

- create a secondary data connection to the list
- when a project number is entered, query the secondary data connection and use that entry to filter the result. You can do this with a change action for the project number field
- if it returns a result, then it already exists and you can use that to set a flag that shows an error message.

There are plenty of examples for this scenario on the web, you just need to dig a little bit, because things are moving away from InfoPath.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found similar solution on searching but since it is an external list, secondary data connection is not supported in Infopath. I was hoping to find a work around to this limitation.

Comment: My experience with external data sources in an SharePoint list Infopath form was not very positive and I have rewritten several solutions that used external data sources in addition to SharePoint list data. They were just too slow.

Comment: Thanks for your input. If possible can you please mention some ways you used to move away from external data sources in SP but still be able to use database data.

Comment: You could create a duplicate of the external data source in a SharePoint list and use a daily background routine to refresh it. That background routine could be built by a developer and use some kind of middleware technology, not something you would necessarily be able to build yourself.